# In Excel is there a way to have the top of a page be an editing, viewing area for details that appear in a list below?

Tags: excel, macos, office365

I'm sorry but I am not sure how to explain this so perhaps I can show that with a picture.

```
Id:       4
English:  Here is an area to enter a lot of data
Japanese: Japanese language meaning of the above


Id        English                Japanese
1         abc                    def
2         ghi                    jol
3         mno                    per
4         Here is an area to ..  Japanese Language meaning of the above
5         aaa                    bbb
```

At the top of the screen I would like an editing area where I can see the full text and enter new.  While below I would like the many rows of data and when I click on any part of a row I would like it to appear above.

I would be okay to code a solution if there was some kind of example I could find but right now I am not even sure what to look for or if this kind of form has a particular name.

Comment: No, but that can be done in 2 minutes with Access ! (continuous form + details in form header)

Comment: I was tending towards Excel as I have 15,000 rows and growing and I am wanting to have many different ways to filter that. Can Access be a front end to an Excel Table so that I could access in multiple ways?

Comment: Access can be a front-end to an Excel list. Just link that workbook.sheet into your Access db. But franky, I would definitely store my data in Access ! And by the way, you can build an Excel pivot based on an Access table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of utilizing actual worksheet space for this task, you can simply create a userform.

## Creating the userform

- In the VBE, right click your project > Insert > Userform
- Add 3 textboxes to represent the columns of the data, and add labels

  - In my example, I added a 4th textbox to indicate the row number. You can use this textbox to change the row # without clicking on the sheet if desired
- Add two command buttons, one that will update the sheet with any text you've made adjustments to and the other that will exit the form.
- Name the objects to something meaningful

  - I named the userform `ufDataViewer`

    - This can be done in the Properties Viewer under `(Name)`
      [image]
  - Name the Update button to `btnUpdate`
  - Name the Cancel button to `btnCancel`
  - Name the ID textbox to `tbID`
  - Name the row # box to `tbRow`
  - Name the English textbox to `tbEnglish`
  - And finally, name the final textbox to `tbJapanese`

**Example of the created userform:**
[image]

## Detecting selection changes

In the worksheet's code module, you can use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event to automatically update the text in your userform. In the VBE, select the specific sheet that you want to watch for these changes, and add the following code block:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ufDataViewer
        .tbID.Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value
        .tbRow.Value = Target.Row
        .tbEnglish.Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value
        .tbJapanese.Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The above block is what will automatically update your userform with the data you manually select by clicking inside of a row.

## Method to show the form

We need to add some code to show the userform. We have a few ways to handle this, and you can mix & match any of these methods *(You do not need to do all of these!)*.

> #### Show the userform when the workbook is opened
>
> In the VBE Project explorer, double-click `ThisWorkbook` and add the following code block:
>
> ```vb
> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>     ufDataViewer.Show vbModeless
> End Sub
> ```

> For the next two methods, you will first need to create a routine in a public module that will show the userform. In the project explorer, right click your project and insert a `Module`. Add this code to this module:
>
> ```vb
> Sub showUserform()
>     ufDataViewer.Show vbModeless
> End Sub
> ```
>
> > #### Use the macro dialog box
> >
> > You can simply run the above code by simultaneously pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> keys and selecting `showUserform` and clicking <kbd>Run</kbd>.
>
> > #### Show the userform from a worksheet command button
> >
> > 1. Add a command button by going to the worksheet and navigating to the `Developer Tab` *(If this is not visible, [here are the steps to activate it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45).)*
> > 2. When you see this tab, click **Insert** and under **Form Controls**, click `Button`.
> > 3. You can now drag a button onto your worksheet. You can select the location and the size of this control. After you finished drawing your button, a dialog box will show. Select the name of the code you just added above: `showUserForm`

## Coding the UserForm

Right-click your userform in the Project Explorer, and select `View Code`. Here is where we are going to assign various functions to your userform. First, let's add a module-scoped variable that will refer to your worksheet. At the top of the code module, enter these two lines:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private ws As Worksheet
```

Next, we will add some code that will determines what will happens when your form is initialized. First, we want to set the `ws` variable that was just created above to the worksheet that you will be using this form on. Since you didn't specify the sheet name in your question, we will use the worksheet name `Sheet1` (feel free to update the ws name here).

We also want to go ahead and auto-populate the textboxes in the userform. This will look strikingly similar to the code we entered in the Sheet's code module above.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Target As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate
    Set Target = ActiveCell
    Me.tbID.Value = ws.Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value
    Me.tbRow.Value = Target.Row
    Me.tbEnglish.Value = ws.Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value
    Me.tbJapanese.Value = ws.Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value
End Sub
```

Detect changes to the `tbRow` textbox to auto-populate the userform if this value is changed:

```vb
Private Sub tbRow_Change()
    If IsNumeric(tbRow.Value) Then
        Me.tbID.Value = ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, "A").Value
        Me.tbEnglish.Value = ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, "B").Value
        Me.tbJapanese.Value = ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, "C").Value
        ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, 1).Select 'Optional if you want to see row's raw data
    End If
End Sub
```

Phew, so now we have allowed your userform to auto-populate by either a selection change or by updating the textbox in the userform itself. Next, we need a method to change the cell values in your worksheet. We will do this by using your Update button. Here's the code:

```vb
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
    If IsNumeric(tbRow.Value) Then
        ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, 1) = tbID.Value
        ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, 2) = tbEnglish.Value
        ws.Cells(tbRow.Value, 3) = tbJapanese.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a numeric value in the Row # textbox or reselect the row!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, when need a way to close the form once you're finished. We can use the click event for your cancel button to do this. Here's the code for that event:

```vb
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

---

### Preview

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Office 365, the scenario you describe would be more fitting to a SharePoint list, where you can edit a row of data in a form.

It is not clear how Office365 impacts on your question, as it is a licensing model and not a software version.

In Desktop Excel you can use Excel Table objects as a data source and create VBA forms for data entry and display. There are many, many examples for that on the web and on this site.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion and yes I am using Office 365.  However the spreadsheet has around 15,000 rows and would also like to somehow have options to filter that down.  I'm not sure all that's possible with Sharepoint.  I will look into Excel Table objects and the use of VBA forms.

Comment: Do you happen to know if Excel Table object and use of VBA forms is also available on the slimmed down version of Excel 365 that runs on the Mac OS?

Comment: Yes, Excel 365 for Mac can use VBA forms and tables.

Answer (score 1):

I use excel, and this piece of code works fine on my side, not sure if this works for office 365 for you.

First freeze the title and above rows.

Then, if your data is on sheet1, then the following two piece of code has to be on sheet1 as well as these are worksheet event functions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)    'show data of the select cells

Dim activergn, insctrgn  ' active range and intersect range

Set activergn = Range("a7:c" & Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row)   ' initial range, you could use "7:"& Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row to achive "any part of the row"
Set insctrgn = Application.Intersect(Target, activergn)

If Not insctrgn Is Nothing Then 'if target range is in the datarange,then B3 & C3 show the value of target address

    Range("b1").Value = "$B$" & insctrgn.Row
    Range("b2").Value = Range("a" & insctrgn.Row).Value
    Range("b3").Value = Range("b" & insctrgn.Row).Value
    Range("b4").Value = Range("c" & insctrgn.Row).Value
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'when value in cell b3 change, update target cell

If Target.Address = Range("b3").Address Then 'if edit in cell B3, then update target cell to value of B3
    Range(Range("b1").Value).Value = Target.Value
    Exit Sub
End If


End Sub
```

[image]